# The number of windows displayed on the computer screen?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to count the number of windows displayed on the computer screen in C#. Who can help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way. Using Win32

```
namespace TestConsole
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System;
    using System.Text;


    public class CountWindows
    {

        public delegate bool EnumDelegate(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam);


        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);


        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowText",
        ExactSpelling = false, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpWindowText, int nMaxCount);


        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "EnumDesktopWindows",
        ExactSpelling = false, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr hDesktop, EnumDelegate lpEnumCallbackFunction, IntPtr lParam);


        static void Main()
        {
            var collection = new List<string>();
            CountWindows.EnumDelegate filter = delegate (IntPtr hWnd, int lParam)
            {
                StringBuilder strbTitle = new StringBuilder(255);
                int nLength = CountWindows.GetWindowText(hWnd, strbTitle, strbTitle.Capacity + 1);
                string strTitle = strbTitle.ToString();

                if (CountWindows.IsWindowVisible(hWnd) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(strTitle) == false)
                {
                    collection.Add(strTitle);
                }
                return true;
            };

            if (CountWindows.EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr.Zero, filter, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                foreach (var item in collection)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Count : "+ collection.Count);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }


}
```